# Суммировать все значения в Java

Tags: java

Привет, проблема с подсчетом общей суммы, из списка выводит только последнюю сумму, нужно чтобы считались все... буду признателен за помощь

```
public void display() {
        defaultTableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements(); //deleted
        defaultTableModel.fireTableDataChanged(); //deleted

        //создаем таблицу
        try {
            List<Record> records = RecordDao.getDao().queryForAll(); //запросить все данные из таблицы своей бд
            // перебираем все объекты и добавляем их  втаблицу
            for (Record record : records) {
                if (employee.getId() == record.getEmployee_id()) {
                    Object[] row = new Object[]{
                            record, // объект в целом
                            employee.getName(), // из первой таблицы где только имена
                            record.getMoney(), // выплаты
                            DateUtils.convert(record.getDate()), // задали дату в приемлимый текст (07.02.12 15:34)
                    };
                    defaultTableModel.addRow(row);
                    jLabel.setText(String.valueOf("Общая сумма всех выплат: " + record.plusSum(record.getMoney())));
                    jLabel.setSize(150, 20);
                    jLabel.setLocation(10, 220);
                    jPanel.add(jLabel);

                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Метод для сложения в классе Record

```
public int plusSum(int allMoney){
    allMoney = allMoney + money;
    return allMoney;
}
```

Comment: А в отладчике что? jPanel.add вообще вызывается для каждого элемента списка?

Comment: Не совсем понял... ?

Comment: В отладчике как код выполняется? jPanel.add() вызывается для каждого элемента списка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты вызываешь метод plusSum у каждого Record, но ты нигде не сохраняешь результат. Тебе нужно где-то сохранить результат. Варианты всякие можно придумать. Самый простой, сделать ПЕРЕД циклом переменную `sum`. Потом в цикле делать `sum = record.plusSum(record.getMoney())`. Когда цикл выполнится, у тебя будет сумма всех записей. Потом эту переменную остается только вывести куда тебе надо. Но это всего один вариант из множества.

Comment: хотя, в таком случае, метод plusSum вообще не уместен. проще делать sum += record.getMoney()

Comment: все верно) спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
jLabel.setText(String.valueOf("Общая сумма всех выплат: " + record.plusSum(record.getMoney())));

public int plusSum(int allMoney){
    allMoney = allMoney + money;
    return allMoney;
}
```

Не увидел тут, почему должна посчитаться вся сумма. В `plusSum` Вы передаете выплаты, что-то с ними складываете `money` и выводите это. Но нигде не вижу сохранения результатов сложения. Почему вообще вы считаете, что должна посчитаться общая сумма?